# Add class for the only one element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, click, toggle

I am trying to make an item selection in React. You can see my code below. When I click on the item, they all selected, but my goal is to click only those that i clicked on. How can I do this? I found same questions, but I cannot figure out what to do with my code.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import prodList from "./prodList";

class RenderItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = { addClass: false };
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ addClass: !this.state.addClass });
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="products-block">{this.renderItems()}</div>;
  }

  renderItems() {
    return prodList.map(this.renderItem.bind(this));
  }

  renderItem(product, i) {
    var someElementClass = this.state.addClass ? "clicked" : "";

    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <div className="products-block-item-card" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <div className="products-block-item-card-decor">
            <div className="products-block-item-card-info">
              <div className="products-block-item-card-description">
                {someElementClass}
                {product.description}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of clicked item somehow. For this purpose we can store clicked item index in state variable `clickedItem`.

```
...

class RenderItem extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {clickedItem: null};
}

handleClick(i) {
    this.setState({clickedItem: i});
}
render() {
    return <div className="products-block">
        { this.renderItems() }
    </div>;
}

renderItems() {
    return prodList.map(this.renderItem.bind(this))
}

renderItem(product, i) {
    var someElementClass = this.state.clickedItem === i ? 'clicked' : '';

    return <div key={i}>

        <div className="products-block-item-card" onClick={() this.handleClick(i)}>
            <div className="products-block-item-card-decor">
                <div className="products-block-item-card-info">
                    <div className="products-block-item-card-description">

                        {someElementClass}
                        {product.description}
                    </div>             
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>           
    </div>
}
}
```